# Emulate USB stick from other device

Tags: usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, emulator

I need to upgrade my monitor, but at my current physical location I am without an USB drive. I was wondering if it is possible to:

1. Create a new partition on say 30 megabytes
2. Move the firmware upgrade files to this partition
3. Plug in a USB-C -> USB2.0 cable into my MacBook and then
4. Point this USB port to the specific partition, so whatever device that connects to this USB2.0 port, will treat it like any other USB stick

This way it would be possible to update my monitor's firmware which requires data to be transferred via USB, without actually having an USB stick

Answer (score 0):

Is the other computer also an Apple?  Use Target Disk Mode.
Apple's support page on this:

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-mac-computers-target-disk-mode-mchlp1443/mac

9to5 Mac YouTube video demonstrating this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUZQwl5DXu8

I would like to see a solution that does not require rebooting into target disk mode.  If someone has a solution that allows keeping the computer booted into macOS while still being able to offer a drive, real or virtual, to another computer then please share.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Keep in mind that it is my external monitor that needs to read data from the USB-C output port (through a USB2.0 port that is on the monitor) so I don't think target disk mode will work, as that will turn off the computer and boot into the usb. The USB will not have a bootable drive, I guess, just some files needed by the monitor to upgrade it's firmware, so don't think that would work unfortunately.